# syntax highlighting while rendering SQL using knitr

Tags: mysql, r, syntax-highlighting, knitr

knitr will execute SQL code using `engine='mysql'` but not highlight syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<engine='mysql', engine.opts="-h localhost">>=
SHOW DATABASES;
@
\end{document}
```

On the other hand using `engine='highlight'` will highlight the code but not execute it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<engine='highlight', engine.opts='-S sql -O latex'>>=
SHOW DATABASES;
@
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to have the code executed **and** the syntax highlighted using one chunk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just [added](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/80e9f86f55a1a0b63048d52a511c94817fb0295b) support for syntax highlighting for the `mysql` engine in **knitr**. You can use **knitr** (>= 1.12.7), which is currently [on Github](https://github.com/yihui/knitr#installation).

Comment: Thanks! You are amazing!